# JOOL tree structure

Tags: java, tree, java-stream, inner-join, jool-library

I have a collection of documents: List listDocs. The document has the structure of the form:

> id, level, aoguid, parentguid, formalname, currstatus

. This structure allows you to create a tree structure of addresses. That is: **a country - level 1, a city - level 2, a street - level 3, and so on up to level 7**. Some levels may or may not be. My task: to form json containing the full address and an array of parts making up the full address.

```
{
  "full Address": "Country city street house",
  "parts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "aoguid": 1,
      "parentguid": 0,
      "formalname": "country",
      "currstatus": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "aoguid": 2,
      "parentguid": 1,
      "formalname": "city",
      "currstatus": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "aoguid": 3,
      "parentguid": 2,
      "formalname": "street",
      "currstatus": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "aoguid": 4,
      "parentguid": 3,
      "formalname": "house",
      "currstatus": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The task is complicated by the fact that the project uses mongoDb, not a relational database. But I found that using the JOOL framework, you can make JAVA queries like SQL. I wrote this code:

```
Seq<Document> seq1 = Seq.seq(listDocs).filter(
        it -> isNull(it.get("currstatus")) || "0".equals(it.get("currstatus"))
);
Seq<Document> seq2 = seq1;
Seq<Document> seq3 = seq1;
Seq<Document> seq4 = seq1;
Seq<Document> seq5 = seq1;
Seq<Document> seq6 = seq1;
Seq<Document> seq7 = seq1;

seq1
        .leftOuterJoin(seq2, (l1, l2) -> Objects.equals(l1.get("aoguid"), l2.get("parentguid")))
        .leftOuterJoin(seq3, (l2, l3) -> Objects.equals(l2.v2.get("aoguid"), l3.get("parentguid")))
        .leftOuterJoin(seq4, (l3, l4) -> Objects.equals(l3.v3.get("aoguid"), l4.get("parentguid")))
        .leftOuterJoin(seq5, (l4, l5) -> Objects.equals(l4.v4.get("aoguid"), l5.get("parentguid")))
        .leftOuterJoin(seq6, (l5, l6) -> Objects.equals(l5.v5.get("aoguid"), l6.get("parentguid")))
        .leftOuterJoin(seq7, (l6, l7) -> Objects.equals(l6.v6.get("aoguid"), l7.get("parentguid")))
        .parallel()
        .forEach(it -> {
            System.out.println("Some actions....");
        });
```

But this code does not compile. How can I fix it so that everything works?

Comment: This construct also don't work: 
`seq1.leftOuterJoin(seq2, seq3, seq4, seq5, seq6, seq7, (l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7) ->
                        
        );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous solution is also correct and may come in handy for someone, but I will lay out the one that I eventually sought. This is the final version.

```
@Override
public void saveES(List<Document> listDocs) {
    Seq<Document> root = seq(listDocs).filter(
            it -> ((Integer) it.get("currstatus") == 0) && ((Integer) it.get("aolevel") == 1)
    );

    root
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    seq(listDocs).filter(level_2 -> isNull(level_2.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_2.get("currstatus") == 0)),
                    (a, b) -> checkObjects(a, b)
            )
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    seq(listDocs).filter(level_3 -> isNull(level_3.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_3.get("currstatus") == 0)),
                    (a, b) -> checkObjects(a.v2, b)
            )
            .map(a -> a.v1.concat(a.v2))
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    seq(listDocs).filter(level_4 -> isNull(level_4.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_4.get("currstatus") == 0)),
                    (a, b) -> checkObjects(a.v3, b)
            )
            .map(a -> a.v1.concat(a.v2))
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    seq(listDocs)
                            .filter(level_5 -> isNull(level_5.get("currstatus")) || (nonNull(level_5.get("currstatus")) && (Integer) level_5.get("currstatus") == 0)),
                    (a, b) -> checkObjects(a.v4, b)
            )
            .map(a -> a.v1.concat(a.v2))
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    seq(listDocs).filter(level_6 -> isNull(level_6.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_6.get("currstatus") == 0)),
                    (a, b) -> checkObjects(a.v5, b)
            )
            .map(a -> a.v1.concat(a.v2))
            .leftOuterJoin(
                    seq(listDocs).filter(level_7 -> isNull(level_7.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_7.get("currstatus") == 0)),
                    (a, b) -> checkObjects(a.v6, b)
            )
            .map(a -> a.v1.concat(a.v2))
            .parallel()
            .distinct()
            .forEach(it -> {
                List<Document> objects1 = (List<Document>) it.toList();
                String full = objects1.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(doc -> String.join(" ", doc.getOrDefault("shortname", "") + ".", (String) doc.get("formalname")))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

                List<Document> objects2 = (List<Document>) it.toList();
                List<Entry> entryList = objects2.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(doc -> Entry.builder()
                                .aoid((String) doc.getOrDefault("aoid", ""))
                                .aoGuid((String) doc.getOrDefault("aoguid", ""))
                                .code((String) doc.getOrDefault("code", ""))
                                .offName((String) doc.getOrDefault("offname", ""))
                                .parentGuid((String) doc.getOrDefault("parentguid", ""))
                                .shortName((String) doc.getOrDefault("shortname", ""))
                                .aoLevel((Integer) doc.getOrDefault("aolevel", ""))
                                .postalCode((String) doc.getOrDefault("postalcode", ""))
                                .build())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                log.info(full);
                Address address = new Address(full, entryList);
                searchService.save(address);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
public void saveES(List<Document> listDocs) {
    Seq<Document> l1 = seq(listDocs).filter(
            it -> ((Integer) it.get("currstatus") == 0)
    );

    l1
            .flatMap(level_1 -> seq(listDocs)
                    .filter(level_2 -> isNull(level_2.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_2.get("currstatus") == 0))
                    .filter(level_2 -> Objects.equals(level_1.get("aoguid"), level_2.get("parentguid")))
                    .onEmpty(null)
                    .map(level_2 -> tuple(level_1, level_2))
            )
            .flatMap(level_1_2 -> //                            return tuple(level_1_2.v1, level_1_2.v2, level_3);
                    seq(listDocs)
                    .filter(level_3 -> isNull(level_3.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_3.get("currstatus") == 0))
                    .filter(level_3 -> Objects.equals(level_1_2.v2.get("aoguid"), level_3.get("parentguid")))
                    .onEmpty(null)
                    .map(level_1_2::concat)
            )
            .flatMap(level_1_2_3 -> seq(listDocs)
                    .filter(level_4 -> isNull(level_4.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_4.get("currstatus") == 0))
                    .filter(level_4 -> Objects.equals(level_1_2_3.v2.get("aoguid"), level_4.get("parentguid")))
                    .onEmpty(null)
                    .map(level_1_2_3::concat)
            )
            .flatMap(level_1_2_3_4 -> seq(listDocs)
                    .filter(level_5 -> isNull(level_5.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_5.get("currstatus") == 0))
                    .filter(level_5 -> Objects.equals(level_1_2_3_4.v2.get("aoguid"), level_5.get("parentguid")))
                    .onEmpty(null)
                    .map(level_1_2_3_4::concat)
            )
            .flatMap(level_1_2_3_4_5 -> seq(listDocs)
                    .filter(level_6 -> isNull(level_6.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_6.get("currstatus") == 0))
                    .filter(level_6 -> Objects.equals(level_1_2_3_4_5.v2.get("aoguid"), level_6.get("parentguid")))
                    .onEmpty(null)
                    .map(level_1_2_3_4_5::concat)
            )
            .flatMap(level_1_2_3_4_5_6 -> seq(listDocs)
                    .filter(level_7 -> isNull(level_7.get("currstatus")) || ((Integer) level_7.get("currstatus") == 0))
                    .filter(level_7 -> Objects.equals(level_1_2_3_4_5_6.v2.get("aoguid"), level_7.get("parentguid")))
                    .onEmpty(null)
                    .map(level_1_2_3_4_5_6::concat)
            )
            .parallel()
            .distinct()
            .forEach(it -> {
                log.info(
                        it.v1.get("formalname")
                                + " -> " + it.v2.get("formalname")
                                + " -> " + it.v3.get("formalname")
                                + " -> " + it.v4.get("formalname")
                                + " -> " + it.v5.get("formalname")
                                + " -> " + it.v6.get("formalname")
                                + " -> " + it.v7.get("formalname")
                );
            });
}
```